# How to use element class name in SWF Object plugin of jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flash

I am using SWFObject plugin of jquery to display SWF files within section.

The code follows like this :

```
<div class='slides'>
    <section class='present'>
        <div class='kreator-slide-content'>
            <div id='blank'>
                <!-- i want to display it here -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>  
</div>
```

I managed to write following :

```
<html>   
<head>    
    <script>    
        $(".flash").click(function() {       
            var el=document.getElementById('blank');         
            swfobject.embedSWF("flash/speakers.swf", el, "600", "300", "9.0.115");        
        });    
    </script>     
</head>      
<body></body>    
</html>
```

but here I want to use section class name "present" which is specific and dynamic since my page works as `reveal.js` where each section is a slide.

Comment: Could you explain what's your problem exactly ?

Comment: Thank you,i want display a .swf file on a button click in a particular section,i have three section's in a div in which two will be hiden and visible section will carry class name as "present" ....so whenever user wants to add a flash file to present section ,it should appear on same section not the one which is hiden

Comment: please let me now if you need further info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply write :

```
$('.flash').click(function() {    
    var el = $('.present #blank')[0];
    swfobject.embedSWF('flash/speakers.swf', el, '600', '300', '9.0.115'); 
});
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: Thank you ,it worked perfectly with small correction        $('.flash').click(function() {    
    var el = $('section.present #blank')[0];
    swfobject.embedSWF('flash/speakers.swf', el, '600', '300', '9.0.115'); 
});

Answer (score 0):

If your class name is specific you can use this line of code:

```
var mySpecificClass = $(".present");
```

If your class name is dynamic you can traverse DOM inside out:

```
var myDynamicClass = $("#blank").parent().parent();
```

Or you can get all slides as array and work with them further:

```
var mySlidesArray = $(".slides>section");
```

Comment: there is the problem i'm facing i cannot add a class name in swfobject ,i need to add a id of element ...class name can be a param later which is not going on ex          swfobject.embedSWF("file.swf", id, "width", "height", "version","param","param","param")